# Error in Majorana Operators squaring to the identity

Tags: dirac-matrices, majorana-fermions

Consider the Majorana fermions expressed mathematically in terms of the creation and annihilation operators of second quantization, the ordinary fermionic annihilation and creation operators $\alpha$ and $\alpha^{\dagger }$ can be written in terms of two Majorana operators $\gamma_{1}$ and $\gamma_{2}$ by:
\begin{align}
\alpha           &= \frac{\gamma_1+i\gamma_2}{2}\\
\alpha^{\dagger} &= \frac{\gamma_1-i\gamma_2}{2}
\end{align}

Squaring, one obtains
\begin{align}
\alpha^2+(\alpha^\dagger)^2 &= \frac{1}{4}\left((\gamma_1+i \gamma_2)^2+(\gamma_1-i \gamma_2)^2\right)\\
                            &= \frac{1}{4}\left( 2 \gamma_1^2-2\gamma_2^2+i\{\gamma_1,\gamma_2\}-i\{\gamma_1,\gamma_2\}\right)\\
&= \frac{\gamma_1^2-\gamma_2^2}{2} \tag{1}
\end{align}
Now, noting
\begin{align}
\gamma_1 &= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\\
\gamma_2 &= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & -i\\
0 & 0 & i & 0 \\
0 & i & 0 & 0\\
-i & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Inserting into (1) I obtain
$$\alpha^2+(\alpha^{\dagger})^2 = - \mathbb{I}_4 \tag{2}$$

Now I presume that the negative sign on the right of (2) is wrong, can anyone spot my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: verify $\gamma_1^2=\gamma_2^2=-\Bbb I_4$. (You may wish to also check $\{\gamma_1,\,\gamma_2\}=\Bbb O_4$, so $\alpha^2=\alpha^{\dagger2}=0$.)

Comment: Hello, thanks you for this, I have verified the identities you have in your response and can therefore see I initially made an error, and indeed, $\alpha^2+(\alpha^{\dagger})^2=0$ but the literature states that the square of these operators should equal the identity $\mathbb{I}_4$ so what am I missing?

Comment: @SoboKevSpace What literature have you found claiming $\alpha^2$ is the identity? It obviously vanishes because $\alpha^2|0\rangle=\alpha0=0,\,\alpha^2|1\rangle=\alpha|0\rangle=0$.

Comment: It was in a PDF on spinor formalism that I'll try to find the link for; the claim is that the *sum* of the squares of the two Majorana operators above is the identity. I follow your ket logic above so I believe you above the PDF